# how to catalog 'SQL Database / Bluemix' in my local machine?

Tags: sql, database, db2, ibm-cloud

I'm trying to use the 'SQL Database' on my local machine, as with DB2 client up and running.

I ran the catalog of 'SQL Database' of Bluemix, I managed to connect, but I can not create tables or execute SELECT or anything ...

below errors:

```
[db2inst1@GCPRDB10 ODONTO]$ db2  "select count(*) from xxxxxxxxx"
SQL0805N  Package "NULLID.SQLC2G15 0X41414141414C4959" was not found.  
SQLSTATE=51002

[db2inst1@GCPRDB10 ODONTO]$ db2 "load from /export/ODONTO/data/xxxxxx.ixf OF IXF LOBS FROM /export/ODONTO/lobs MODIFIED BY IDENTITYOVERRIDE insert into xxxxxxx NONRECOVERABLE"
SQL2019N  An error occurred while binding the utilities to the database.
```

I used to catalog the following commands:

```
db2 catalog tcpip node bluemix remote xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx server 50000
db2 catalog db SQLDB as ODONTO at node bluemix
```

Thanks ;)

Comment: My guess would be that your client version may not match that of the server.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably connecting to SQLDB on Bluemix using a wrong version for libraries / client

Follow what is suggested  on

https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SQLDB/index.html

in the section

Connect ODBC or CLI applications from outside Bluemix

Comment: My client was 10.1, upgrade to 10.5 and it worked perfectly. thank you!

Comment: I am glad to know this. Please could you accept the answer?